# Mailbox is always full while CAN communication in STM32. I used more than one transceiver integrated but the problem did not change

Tags: stm32, can-bus

I use SN65HVD230 and MCP2551 ICs to make CAN communication with STM32. In communications, the mailbox is constantly filling up and hangs at the place specified in the code below. Or when I observed CAN H and CAN L on the oscilloscope, they are the same. not differential. But the devices are all the same. the codes i have used, why the codes i shared in the attached link can't be run, i don't do anything different. PLEASE HELP ME

https://controllerstech.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/STM32_CAN_COM.zip

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan, CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef *pHeader, uint8_t aData[], uint32_t *pTxMailbox)
{
  uint32_t transmitmailbox;
  HAL_CAN_StateTypeDef state = hcan->State;
  uint32_t tsr = READ_REG(hcan->Instance->TSR);

  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_CAN_IDTYPE(pHeader->IDE));
  assert_param(IS_CAN_RTR(pHeader->RTR));
  assert_param(IS_CAN_DLC(pHeader->DLC));
  if (pHeader->IDE == CAN_ID_STD)
  {
    assert_param(IS_CAN_STDID(pHeader->StdId));
  }
  else
  {
    assert_param(IS_CAN_EXTID(pHeader->ExtId));
  }
  assert_param(IS_FUNCTIONAL_STATE(pHeader->TransmitGlobalTime));

  if ((state == HAL_CAN_STATE_READY) ||
      (state == HAL_CAN_STATE_LISTENING))
  {
    /* Check that all the Tx mailboxes are not full */
    if (((tsr & CAN_TSR_TME0) != 0U) ||
        ((tsr & CAN_TSR_TME1) != 0U) ||
        ((tsr & CAN_TSR_TME2) != 0U))
    {
      /* Select an empty transmit mailbox */
      transmitmailbox = (tsr & CAN_TSR_CODE) >> CAN_TSR_CODE_Pos;

      /* Check transmit mailbox value */
      if (transmitmailbox > 2U)
      {
        /* Update error code */
        hcan->ErrorCode |= HAL_CAN_ERROR_INTERNAL;

        return HAL_ERROR;
      }

      /* Store the Tx mailbox */
      *pTxMailbox = (uint32_t)1 << transmitmailbox;

      /* Set up the Id */
      if (pHeader->IDE == CAN_ID_STD)
      {
        hcan->Instance->sTxMailBox[transmitmailbox].TIR = ((pHeader->StdId << CAN_TI0R_STID_Pos) |
                                                           pHeader->RTR);
      }
      else
      {
        hcan->Instance->sTxMailBox[transmitmailbox].TIR = ((pHeader->ExtId << CAN_TI0R_EXID_Pos) |
                                                           pHeader->IDE |
                                                           pHeader->RTR);
      }

      /* Set up the DLC */
      hcan->Instance->sTxMailBox[transmitmailbox].TDTR = (pHeader->DLC);

      /* Set up the Transmit Global Time mode */
      if (pHeader->TransmitGlobalTime == ENABLE)
      {
        SET_BIT(hcan->Instance->sTxMailBox[transmitmailbox].TDTR, CAN_TDT0R_TGT);
      }

      /* Set up the data field */
      WRITE_REG(hcan->Instance->sTxMailBox[transmitmailbox].TDHR,
                ((uint32_t)aData[7] << CAN_TDH0R_DATA7_Pos) |
                ((uint32_t)aData[6] << CAN_TDH0R_DATA6_Pos) |
                ((uint32_t)aData[5] << CAN_TDH0R_DATA5_Pos) |
                ((uint32_t)aData[4] << CAN_TDH0R_DATA4_Pos));
      WRITE_REG(hcan->Instance->sTxMailBox[transmitmailbox].TDLR,
                ((uint32_t)aData[3] << CAN_TDL0R_DATA3_Pos) |
                ((uint32_t)aData[2] << CAN_TDL0R_DATA2_Pos) |
                ((uint32_t)aData[1] << CAN_TDL0R_DATA1_Pos) |
                ((uint32_t)aData[0] << CAN_TDL0R_DATA0_Pos));

      /* Request transmission */
      SET_BIT(hcan->Instance->sTxMailBox[transmitmailbox].TIR, CAN_TI0R_TXRQ);

      /* Return function status */
      return HAL_OK;
    }
    else
    {
      /* Update error code */
      hcan->ErrorCode |= HAL_CAN_ERROR_PARAM; ////////// ERROR HERE////////////

      return HAL_ERROR;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    /* Update error code */
    hcan->ErrorCode |= HAL_CAN_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED;

    return HAL_ERROR;
  }
}
```